# Paginated Data Table after next page data can not show only loading

Tags: flutter, dart

this problem can't show a data, even next page only loading.

i'm stak to fixing this code, maybe anyone can help me to fixing this problem.

---

this is a code to create paginatedDataTable, even i running this code i can't to next page, data not show only loading. i hope any a solution for me with this code. and please to give example.

thank you very much.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:mobile_ess/helpers/url_helper.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PicHrgs extends StatefulWidget {
  const PicHrgs({super.key});

  @override
  State<PicHrgs> createState() => _PicHrgsState();
}

class _PicHrgsState extends State<PicHrgs> {
  final MyDataSource dataSource = MyDataSource();
  late int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  late int _pageIndex = 0;
  late int _rowCount = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: PaginatedDataTable(
        columns: const <DataColumn>[
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('NRP'),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Text('Nama'),
          ),
        ],
        source: dataSource,
        rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
        onRowsPerPageChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _rowsPerPage = value!;
            dataSource.fetchDataFromApi(pageIndex: _pageIndex);
          });
        },
        onPageChanged: (pageIndex) {
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
            dataSource.fetchDataFromApi(
                pageIndex: _pageIndex); // Fetch data for the new page
          });
        },
        availableRowsPerPage: const [
          5,
          10,
          20,
          100,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dataSource.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        _rowCount = dataSource.rowCount;
      });
    });
    dataSource.fetchDataFromApi(pageIndex: _pageIndex);
  }
}

class MyDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  late List<List<Comparable<Object>>> _data = [];
  late int _rowsPerPage = PaginatedDataTable.defaultRowsPerPage;
  late int _pageIndex = 1;
  late int _rowCount = 0;
  final String apiUrl = API_URL;
  Future<void> fetchDataFromApi(
      {required int pageIndex, String searchQuery = ''}) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? token = prefs.getString('token');
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          "$apiUrl/master/hrgs/get?page=$_pageIndex&perPage=$_rowsPerPage&search=$searchQuery"),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print(
      Uri.parse(
          "$apiUrl/master/hrgs/get?page=$_pageIndex&perPage=$_rowsPerPage&search=$searchQuery"),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      final List<dynamic> dataku = responseData['dataku'];
      final total = responseData["totalPage"];
      _rowCount = total['total_records'] ?? 0;
      _data = dataku.map<List<Comparable<Object>>>((data) {
        return [
          data['nrp'] ?? '',
          data['nama'] ?? '',
        ];
      }).toList();
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data from API');
    }
  }

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < _data.length) {
      return DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(_data[index][0].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(_data[index][1].toString())),
      ]);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => _data.length | _rowCount;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```